# Page cannot be null

Tags: asp.net, null

I am using a ScriptManager in my aspx page and when I run on the submit button within the page I am receiving a "Page cannot be null" error message. I have looked around but cannot find anything that deals with this.

I am writing in C# using VS2008 with the latest .NET framework, and the ScriptManager is for two Infragistics controls for multiline purposes

Can anyone help please

Comment: Can you provide us with a piece of aspx-code, whereby you include the ScriptManager? And if possible the stacktrace and further exception details?

Comment: Nevermind, it was all on me, I put it into a div which was used for showing not controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A word to the wise, review your code before asking a question so you wont look foolish like I did. The problem laid within the scriptmanager control being placed into a div tag that was meant to not show any controls.